# How do we denote the class of all functions with a given target?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

Suppose that $S$ is a set. What is a standard notation for the class
$$
\{f : X \to Y | Y = S, X \text{ set}\} ?
$$

Alternatively, how do we denote the class of all arbitrarily large tuples with elements in $S$?

EDIT: I would prefer a notation that does not use category theory, and I'd also be happy with "educated inventions".

Comment: I don't recall any particular notation for this sort of class.

Comment: Isn't it $Set/S$, in a categorical notation ?

Comment: @Max What is the concept called that this notation represents in general?

Comment: Concerning your edit: then I fear that you must come up with some notation created by yourself. Let's wait and see, though. I am curious.

Comment: It's colled the slice category over $S$

Comment: @Max thanks, that means it's the same as in the answer below.

Answer (score 3):

If $S$ is a set then it can be interpreted as an object in category $\mathbf{Set}$.

Object $S$ induces the [slice category](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_category#Slice_category) $(\mathbf{Set}\downarrow S)$ and objects of this category are arrows in $\mathbf{Set}$ (which are functions) that have $S$ as codomain.

So you could denote the class by: $$\text{Ob}(\mathbf{Set}\downarrow S)$$

Of course this is only recommendable if it is presented to people who are familiar with these concepts.

Comment: Nice! I was previously unfamiliar with comma categories, but I quite like the concept.